# 18.04 Server can log in remote but not local

Tags: 18.04, login, xfce

After reading through the forums, I feel I have the opposite issue of most remote access issues.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 Server and logged in.  Installed Xfce desktop and Mozilla Firefox to allow me to look up additional information about configuring a Dual Wan (and bonded nic) setup.  Everything worked fine.  Set up a 3rd (as #2/#3 are bonded) NIC with the intention of using it as LAN only / remote in from my desktop.

Able to SSH in with putty, but noticed I've got some routing/NAT weirdness going on, as websites either load instantly  / time out, same with sudo apt-get update, etc...  Assuming they're going out/coming in on the different interfaces.  Went back in to log in locally today on the server and it's saying "Failed to Execute Login Command", screen flashes something to quick to read and then refreshes the desktop.

As it had been a week since I'd been able to work the project, I thought 'Dummy, you must have put the password in wrong'. After several attempts, I came back to my desktop in the office and tried to SSH in with the same username/password and got right in!

So, I have access to continue to try and fix w/e weird routing/NAT/whatever issue I have through SSH, but cannot log in local now and have no idea why.  Possibly some sort of Xfce Desktop issue?  At this point I would even take shutting down the desktop log in locally without the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I found out.  As I was troubleshooting other issues that had shown up (prior to getting on to the routing/NAT issue, I found that I now had no way to even run sudo apt-get update, as I was getting all sorts of 'Failed to write, drive full' errors).

Long story short, apparently even though I have a 410G raid set up on the server and had partitioned it with LVM upon the original install, only 4GB was actually being used from the installer on root and I had the following:

**System information as of Sat Jun  8 15:40:10 UTC 2019
  => / is using 95.7% of 3.87GB**

After resizing the **/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.8G     0 100% /** I thought I'd try to log in and Voila! I was able to log in again.  Not sure if I missed something the night I did the install or what, as previously I had always done up specific partition sizes based off of what I'd read online (e.g. separate root / tmp / home / etc) but this time I went with what everyone recommended was let it do LVM and let it auto populate/adjust.  It gave me the full 410GB on the LVM but stuck root at 4gb which had filled up, thus not letting me log in with the GUI (local) nor do any updates/etc.

Figured I would post the solution I found in case anyone else had issues with not being able to log in to the Desktop GUI and turns out it was a full root partition.  Thanks all!  ~AW